# Cannot send mails with WSO2 EMM

Tags: wso2, mdm, wso2-iot

I'm not able to send mails with wso2 EMM v1.0.1, no matter how I configure the mail settings.
Can someone who managed to do this tell me how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: apparently, I just figured out, the type of communication is hardcoded to 'tls' in the code.
It seems that this js function can have 4 params as well, so when you just delete the last parameter in the call (with 'tls'), it works!
This needs to be done in all user.js files (line ~435) in the modules folder for MDM and MAM.

Answer (score 0):

What is the email server you gonna connect? EMM version 1.0.0 had an issue connecting to secure email servers (SES) which has been fixed in 1.1.0 version. Try connecting to a gmail server and see whether you can send mails.

Comment: Connected to a local RoundCube (open-source) mail server. If I recall correctly also not possible to connect to GMail. But as you mentioned indeed only issues with Secure mail servers, since 'tls' seemed to have been hardcoded in the user.js files so that any other protocol couldn't be used.

Comment: Yes it uses tls and you can change the code from their for alternatives. Also its missing the login credentials other than the sender email etc. Anyway you can connect to gmail and we have tested that thoroughly. Can you list down your settings?